# list of pages loaded in RAM for a process

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

can any body please tell me, in linux kernel, how can i print the list of start address of all the  pages which are loaded in the RAM.

Comment: Assuming your system has 4 KB pages, which most do, that list is just every multiple of 4096 from 0 up to the size of RAM.  Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: yeah...but that wont be contiguous w.r.t a process. Each process will have a region of those pages (VMA). Something lime proc/<pid>maps prints

Comment: Well, presumably the kernel generates the information that's in `proc/<pid>maps`, right?  Check out that code and see how it's done!

Comment: cat [/proc/{pid}/smaps](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc)

Comment: how should i go about the in-memory pages which are non-anonymuous. Any related code to achieve that. I am asking as i am a beginner.

Comment: to be more specific, is there a way in code to find that the particular page is in memory or not ?